# Drupal 7 Ajax Form, add elements dynamically to a fieldset

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have the following form:

```
  $form['#tree'] = TRUE;

  $tasks = array(
    'Julia',
    'John',
  );

  foreach ($tasks as $task_key => $task) {

    $form['task_fieldset'][$task_key] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $task,
      '#prefix' => '<div id="task-' . $task_key . '-fieldset-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    if (empty($form_state['num_todos'][$task_key])) {
      $form_state['num_todos'][$task_key] = 1;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_todos'][$task_key]; $i++) {
      $form['task_fieldset'][$task_key]['todo'][$i] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Todo'),
      );
    }

    $form['task_fieldset'][$task_key]['add_todo'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#name' => 'add_todo_' . $task_key,
      '#value' => t('Add more'),
      '#submit' => array('custom_mod_example_ajax_collection_add_todo'),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'custom_mod_example_ajax_collection_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'task-' . $task_key . '-fieldset-wrapper',
      ),
    );

  }

  return $form;
```

These are the callbacks:

```
function custom_mod_example_ajax_collection_callback($form, $form_state) {
  $name = $form_state['triggering_element']['#name'];

  $task_key = (int) substr($name, strpos($name, "_") + 1);

  return $form['task_fieldset'][$task_key];
}

function custom_mod_example_ajax_collection_add_todo($form, &$form_state) {
  $name = $form_state['triggering_element']['#name'];

  $task_key = (int) substr($name, strpos($name, "_") + 1);

  $form_state['num_todos'][$task_key]++;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

And the form looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwShN.jpg
The problem is that when I click on "Add more" on John fieldset, it changes to Julia. What have I done wrong?

It works as expected when I try Add more on Julia, however.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the AJAX callback, and specifically the code line:

```
$task_key = (int) substr($name, strpos($name, "_") + 1);
```

The buttons are named add_todo_key, and the code above returns todo_key, and not the key.

It was solved simply by using `strrpos`, which find the position of the LAST occurrence of a substring, rather than `strpos` that finds the first.